# PHP together with django in heroku instance

Tags: php, python, django, wordpress, heroku

Is it possible to run some php app (e.g. wordpress) together with django within one heroku instance, so that the part of app's urls would be served by php and the rest by django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, application type is determined at slug compilation time when the application is pushed to Heroku. Not sure if you could do anything with a custom build pack but I would have thought so.

Comment: The only way to do something like this would be to create your own [buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-hello) that supports both runtimes. For reference, here are the official [Python](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python) and [PHP](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php) buildpacks.